# Set Recipient in Sprout Email Notification

Tags: plugin-sproutemail

Okay, so similar issue to this question ([Sprout email notifications - setting the recipient?](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/19505/sprout-email-notifications-setting-the-recipient)). I must be doing something stupid here because. Trying to set the recipient from an entry form, with a hidden field:

```
<input type="hidden" name="recipient" value="{{ 'name@address.co.uk'|hash }}">
```

Then in the control panel, the *Recipients* field has {recipient}. That should work right, but I don't receive the email. If I manually set an email address in the control panel *Recipients* field, it works fine.

Comment: Does it work if you don't hash the email? `value="name@address.co.uk"`

Comment: Hi Simon. Nope, hash or no hash makes no difference.

Comment: Are you using the Sprout Forms Hidden field? Or is this some other field type that you are hard coding in your Form Templates? Sprout Forms does support a default Email Dropdown field that would handle the obfuscation for you for pre-defined email addresses. You could add a hidden class to the field in the CP.

Comment: Hey Ben. It's just my own field. Doesn't need obfuscation really, since this is a members-only page.

Answer (score 1):

This is possible with the Sprout Forms Invisible Field (be sure to update to the latest version). Using the Invisible Field will ensure your email address never shows up in the template. To set this up:

1) Add an Invisible Field (`invisibleFieldHandle`) to your form and set its value to `{recipient}`

2) Setup a Notification Email and set your Recipient field to the name of your Invisible Field Handle: `{invisibleFieldHandle}`

3) Before your Sprout Forms `displayForm` tag, set the value of the Email Address where you want to trigger the Notification Email:

```
{% do craft.sproutForms.addFieldVariables({ 
  recipient: 'email@website.com'
}) %}

{% craft.sproutForms.displayForm('contact') %}
```